# Why does this work in C for init a structure? struct x_ tmp = {{{{0}}}};

Tags: c

I've been hunting around on why this compiles:

```
struct x_ {
    char a[10];
    int  b;
};

struct x_ tmp = {{{{0}}}};
```

We may have an older gcc version, so {0} may not work and {{0}} should be used, but don't see this {{{{0}}}} anywhere. 
See gcc bug here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53119

Thanks
Peter

Comment: MSVC says "Too many initialisers" and you left a syntax error no `;` after the `struct` definition.

Comment: @WeatherVane gcc as well, just fix it ;)

Comment: You can determine exactly which version of gcc you have via `gcc --version`.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the question to be asking whether GCC is correct to accept the specified initializer for an object of the specified type.  To address the question I will be quoting from section 6.7.9 of the C2011 standard.

In the first place, the following applies both to the initializer for the overall struct and to the initializer within for the first member:

> [...] the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be a brace-enclosed list of initializers for the elements or named members.

We then have:

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated *current object*.   [...] subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according
>   to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure members in declaration order [...].

... and later ...

> If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are aggregates or unions, these rules apply recursively to the subaggregates or contained unions.  If the initializer of a subaggregate or contained union begins with a left brace, the initializers enclosed by that brace and its matching right brace initialize the elements or members of the subaggregate or the contained union.

Among those, we have the overall `{{{{0}}}}` established as an initializer for the whole struct, `{{{0}}}` as an initializer for its first member, `a`, and `{{0}}` as an initializer for `a[0]`.  The question comes down to whether the last pairing is a valid.  If it is, then the others are valid, too.

This possibly bears on the matter:

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, *optionally enclosed in braces*.

(emphasis added).  That can be interpreted to specify that the initializer for `a[0]` can be enclosed in braces, i.e. as `{0}`, because `a[0]` is indeed a scalar.  I am not convinced that that's the intended interpretation, but I would not be prepared at this point to fault GCC for accepting it.

I do not, however, accept `{{0}}` as a single expression enclosed in braces, therefore I do not accept it to be a valid initializer for `a[0]`.  I ***speculate*** that GCC accepts it as a result of inappropriate recursive application of the rule allowing scalar initializers to be brace-enclosed.

For what it's worth, GCC 4.4.7 does emit two warnings about the construct by default:

```
i.c:7: warning: braces around scalar initializer
i.c:7: warning: (near initialization for ‘tmp.a[0]’)
i.c:7: warning: braces around scalar initializer
i.c:7: warning: (near initialization for ‘tmp.a[0]’)
```

Evidently, then, someone thought the extra braces were questionable, but the GCC documentation does not mention accepting that form among the supported language extensions.  At minimum, then, there is a documentation bug.

Answer (score -2):

When initializing a struct containing an array, you can either initialize the first element (with the rest set to `0` by default) or you can provide an initialization of each value. In this case using either a *string* initialization for `a`, or an *array-style* initialization providing a value for all members, e.g.

```
struct x_ tmp = { .a="" };  /* using string initialization of a  */
```

or

```
struct x_ tmp = {{0},0};    /* using array initialization format */
```

Failing to identify a specific field, or provide an initialization for all members will generate compiler warnings for *braces around a scalar initializer* and *missing-field-initializers*, while initializing values to `0` by default.

**Example with Use/Output**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct x_ {
    char a[10];
    int  b;
};

int main (void) {

    struct x_ tmp = { .a="" };  /* using string initialization of a  */
    struct x_ tmq = {{0},0};    /* using array initialization format */

    printf ("\n tmp.a : '%s', tmp.b : %d\n", tmp.a, tmp.b);
    printf ("\n tmq.a : '%s', tmq.b : %d\n", tmq.a, tmq.b);

    return 0;
}
```

e.g.

```
$ ./bin/struct_init

 tmp.a : '', tmp.b : 0

 tmq.a : '', tmq.b : 0
```

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter will have the integrity to identify the technical inaccuracy in the example, but chances are they don't.

Comment: The question was not about correct syntax, though `tmp = {0};` is correct as well in this case, but about why `gcc` does compile `tmp = {{{{0}}}};` without errors. I think this was a reason for downvote

Comment: The bug report was filed regarding a single-member array initialization. There isn't any argument that `struct example {int foo[2];};` can be initialized by `struct example ex = {0};`, but that isn't `tmp` in the question.

Comment: This answer does not address the question , which is asking why `struct x_ tmp = {{{{0}}}};` works.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you, If you don't read "*while initializing values to 0 by default.*" to answer why it works, and it make you feel better to downvote -- go ahead, we simply disagree on the interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for the answers - closer to a rational - perhaps I'll post on the gcc forums as well - thanks!